# How to move adapter to fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

```
public class ServiceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ServiceAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private Context context;
    private List<ServiceModel> serviceData;

    public ServiceAdapter(HomeFragment homeFragment, List<ServiceModel> serviceData) {
        this.serviceData = serviceData;
        this.context=context;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ServiceAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view ;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.service_item,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ServiceAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.service_name.setText(serviceData.get(position).getService_name());
    holder.service_image.setImageResource(serviceData.get(position).getService_image());
    holder.service_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ServiceInnerListFragment serviceInnerListFragment = new ServiceInnerListFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.serviceList,serviceInnerListFragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return serviceData.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView service_name;
        ImageView service_image;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            service_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.service_name);
            service_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.service_image);
        }
    }
}
```

> show this error :     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment ServiceInnerListFragment{e3b9496} (62106443-c898-4eb6-87ff-e10611e91548)} not attached to an activity.
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireActivity(Fragment.java:833)
> at com.example.onlineshop.adapter.ServiceAdapter$1.onClick(ServiceAdapter.java:61)
>
> > 61 line is : FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

Answer (score 1):

You should consider to remove all your code from onClick(), because it is not recommended to have such implementation inside your RecyclerView. You can make an interface inside your adapter that send some important information in order to identify what item was clicked and then implement that interface in the activity/fragment that you've called this adapter. Inside onClick() only use that interface to pass information :)

Example: **(!!) All of this is made for passing the position - modify it for your own needs**

1. Define a interface inside your adapter class

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position); //you can pass whatever information you need from the item that will be clicked, here, i want to further use his position in the adapter's list
    }
```

2. Create an instance of your interface in your Adapter class:

```
private OnItemClickListener mListener;
```

3. Create a method to set it when the item is clicked:

```
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }
```

4. Inside your ViewHolder make use of that code above:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            mListener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

5. Inside your Activity/Fragment that you use this adapter:

```
implements "Adapter".OnItemClickListener //your adapter
```

6. Override your onClick interface method:

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        ...
        your code
        - here you have access of that clicked item/property
        ...
}
```

7. At the same moment you use recyclerView.setAdapter() you need to also set the clickListener like this:

```
 "yourAdapter".setOnItemClickListener(activity/fragment);
```

Comment: Thank you, can you give me a example?

Comment: @FazlulHoqueSawrav I've edited my answer to give you an example. Good luck :)